# MAPI Requests - Exchange Server (TCP/RPC) vs IMAP-Connection

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto, imap, mapi

I am currently developing an Outlook VSTO-AddIn using C#. I want to read certain attributes of each mailItem. (E.g. SenderName, SenderEmailAdress, etc. .. )
As far as I have understood I have understood- I have two option for achieving this:

1. Accessing the Outlook object model
2. Using a "Property Accessor Object" to read a MAPI property that belongs to a MailItem but that is not exposed in the Outlook object model. (https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/office/vba/api/outlook.propertyaccessor)

A little Code Snippet for the property accessor:
The `mailItem` is an object of the MailItemClass Class from the Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook namespace.

```
PropertyAccessor olPA = mailItem.PropertyAccessor;
SenderMailAddress = olPA.GetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x0C1F001F");
```

I am encountering the following strange behavior:
The results differ depending on whether I access the mailbox via IMAP or via TCP/RPC-Connections.
Primarily when trying to access attributes of a mailItem sent by someone, whose Account has been removed.
With an IMAP Connection the MAPI-Requests work fine, with TCP/RPC they don't.

Most resources I find on that topic are from 2009-2010, so I am unsure how they translate to the 2016-Version of Outlook.

Any hints that shed light on the difference between TCP/RPC in that case are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is really no distinction between the two: `PR_SENDER_EMAIL_ADDRESS` gets retrieved by both `MailItem.SenderEmailAddress` and by `MailItem.PropertyAccessor.GetProperty`.

Do you actually see the `PR_SENDER_EMAIL_ADDRESS` property when you look at the item with [OutlookSpy](http://www.dimastr.com/outspy/) (I am its author) or [MFCMAPI](https://github.com/stephenegriffin/mfcmapi)?

Comment: Thank you very much!! I hadn't heard of these applications. Even though the PR_SENDER_EMAIL_ADRESS property is set correctly in MFCMAPI, I get something of the form `\OU=(name of my organisatzion, ...\CN=SURNAME LASTNAME` from this attribute. However, I tried using PR_SENDER_SMTP_ADDRESS_A which works fine.